# Microsoft Excel - Fuzzy Lookup Plugin

Tags: microsoft-excel

For anyone who has used the Fuzzy Lookup plugin -

In the case of multi-column fuzzy match, does it make a difference if I choose each column separately in the "Match Columns" or together? What is the difference?

[image: Choosing columns together]
[image: Choosing columns individually]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will make a huge difference to the results. The second option is the way you want to go.

In your first case, the fuzzy lookup will combine all three fields as a single string, and then evaluate the % similarity based on the # of characters in the entire string.

In your second case, having three separate match columns will give equal weight to each comparison. Separate calculations are being performed on the color and the fruit.

The reason having the separate fields (separate calculations) is more accurate is that, lets say the names of the fruit on average are 12 characters in length, and colors on average are 6 characters in length.  If you combine the two strings into one, names are going to have a heavier just because they contain more characters.  When you calculate each field separately, the similarity % will compare name vs name, output a score, then take color vs color and output a separate score.  The % Similarity the averages the two scores together to get the final Similarity %.

Ultimately the answer could be different, depending on what you are looking for, but the second option evaluates each field equally regardless of the length of the words in that string.

...Hope this helps!  I went through a lot of frustrating trial and error before discovering this myself ;)